# SSHKit::Command::Failed: gulp exit status: 256

Tags: ruby, gulp, capistrano

Running Capistrano. Worked yesterday, not working today. Here's the main error. It's with Gulp... Ran `gulp -v` and both local and global are 3.9.0

```
INFO[17d08d58] Running /usr/bin/env gulp --production --no-color on localhost
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Command::Failed: gulp exit status: 256
gulp stdout: [10:25:28] Using gulpfile ...gulpfile.js
[10:25:28] Starting 'clean'...
[10:25:28] Finished 'clean' after 14 ms
[10:25:28] Starting 'default'...
[10:25:28] Starting 'wiredep'...
[10:25:28] Starting 'scssLint'...
[10:25:28] Finished 'scssLint' after 13 μs
[10:25:28] Starting 'jshint'...
[10:25:29] Starting 'browserify'...
[10:25:29] Starting 'fonts'...
[10:25:29] Starting 'images'...
[10:25:29] Finished 'default' after 1.08 s
[10:25:30] Finished 'wiredep' after 1.34 s
[10:25:30] Starting 'styles'...
gulp stderr: stream.js:94
  throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
        ^
Error: invalid top-level expression
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I also ran `capistrano-ssh-doctor` and everything was working great.

Answer (score 0):

FOUND IT! It was within the SASS code - there was an error and thus it did not compile properly.